Cannot get html/markdown preview on both Marker and Playhouse (Gnome)
I'm trying to build a simple html page, and either Playhouse and Marker look ideal to me: I like the minimalist philosophy they have, and basically have all of the functionality a beginner like me needs.
The issue is that both of them are broken for me, and it looks like the same bug: the preview panel is blank. I think the text is there, since I can select it with CTRL+a, and paste it to a text editor, but the panel itself is empty.
For example, here is how it looks on Playhouse:

Any ideas whats going on?
I installed both of them from Flathub (and tried Marker also as an rpm), on a fully updated Fedora Workstation.
